# how to describe "this much" for countable noun

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns

I could say "I have this much of time"
But for like on Facebook, i supposed it's countable: 1 like 2 like.

`How to say "I have this much of likes?"`

Comment: I'm not convinced you ***can*** say "I have this much of time". Not in any context I can think of, anyway. You can certainly have ***this much time*** or ***this many likes***, though,

Comment: I have this many likes, but you should really ask this question on ELL, (English Language Learning)

Comment: With the quantity phrase _this much_, one must designate some measure standard. Holding up a coffee cup would do, or holding the thumb and forefinger an inch apart. But  the _this_ has to have a referent, and it is usually a gestural referent.