# Much + Noun nuance (this much earth surface)

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs

What does "much" add in this construction?

> This much earth surface has to fit onto this much map surface

compared to

> This earth surface has to fit onto this map surface

Context:

> [image]

---

I found [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/268782/5023) without answer, but I'm not sure this is related.

Comment: The word ***much*** isn't *essential* in the cited context (in the *first* use). And potentially it could be confusing that the syntactic role / exact meaning of the word is different in the two places it occurs on the diagram. The first use could be directly replaced by *[this] **area of** [earth surface]* ("neutral" as regard large or small), whereas the second one specifically implies *a **significantly large fraction** [of the total surface of the earth]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paraphrase "much" as "amount of".

> This (amount of) earth surface has to fit on this (amount of) map.

The point being that the surface is curved so there is more of it than space on the map, and so it must be deformed to fit the flat map.

The word "much" indicates we are talking about the area, or size of the two surfaces.

There is a second use of "much":

> Much of the earth's surface has to...

In this case it could be paraphrased as "A large proportion of"